# Apache PIG - set date of current row as the next records' date

Tags: apache-pig

In Pig, I have requirement to set avail_until as next records' avail_since given a particular id and default it to 9999-12-31 for the last record of a given id. I'm starting out by ordering the data by ID and then Avail_Since but am stuck after that. I think I may need an over/stitch/lead/lag function but not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 Input Data:

 ID       AVAIL_SINCE    AVAIL_UNTIL
 1        19-Jan-00      31-Dec-99
 1        11-Jun-00      31-Dec-99
 1        4-Aug-00       31-Dec-99
 1        19-May-01      31-Dec-99 
 2        5-May-02       31-Dec-99 
 2        8-Apr-03       31-Dec-99 
 3        10-Jun-00      31-Dec-99 
 3        31-Oct-00      31-Dec-99 
 3        29-Dec-00      31-Dec-99  

 Required Result:

 ID       AVAIL_SINCE    AVAIL_UNTIL
 1        19-Jan-00      11-Jun-00
 1        11-Jun-00      4-Aug-00
 1        4-Aug-00       19-May-01
 1        19-May-01      31-Dec-99
 2        5-May-02       8-Apr-03 
 2        8-Apr-03       31-Dec-99
 3        10-Jun-00      31-Oct-00
 3        31-Oct-00      29-Dec-00
 3        29-Dec-00      31-Dec-99
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to load the data twice, rank it to generate unique ids,filter top records from the second dataset,rank it again, then join the datasets on the unique ids,get the last record from the first dataset and union it with the joined dataset.See below

Script

```
A = LOAD 'test9.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (A1:int,A2:chararray,A3:chararray);
B = LOAD 'test9.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (B1:int,B2:chararray,B3:chararray);
RankA = rank A;
RankB = rank B;

BB = FILTER RankB by (rank_B > 1);
BB_New = rank BB;

AB = JOIN RankA by rank_A,BB_New by rank_BB;
AB_ALL = foreach AB GENERATE RankA::A1,RankA::A2,BB_New::B2;
A_Order = ORDER RankA by rank_A desc;
A_Last = LIMIT A_Order 1;
A_Fields = foreach A_Last generate $1,$2,$3;

FINAL = UNION A_Fields,AB_ALL;
FINALORDER = ORDER FINAL BY $0;
DUMP FINALORDER;
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will extend the solution of @inuistive_mind to get the exact result..

```
A = LOAD 'test9.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (A1:int,A2:chararray,A3:chararray);
B = LOAD 'test9.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (B1:int,B2:chararray,B3:chararray);
RankA = rank A;
RankB = rank B;

BB = FILTER RankB by (rank_B > 1);
BB_New = rank BB;

AB = JOIN RankA by rank_A,BB_New by rank_BB;
AB_ALL = foreach AB GENERATE RankA::A1,RankA::A2,BB_New::B2;
A_Order = ORDER RankA by rank_A desc;
A_Last = LIMIT A_Order 1;
A_Fields = foreach A_Last generate $1,$2,$3;

FINAL = UNION A_Fields,AB_ALL;
FINALORDER = ORDER FINAL BY $0;
```

Steps Need to be added

```
Step-1  F1 = rank FINALORDER..
Step-2  Group BY A1; ie ID.
Step-3  F2 = foreach byid generate MAX(FINAL.rank_FINAL) AS mx, '31-Dec-99' as AVAIL_UNTIL1.
Step-4  F3 = join F1 by rank_FINALORDER with F2 by mx as left outer join.
Step-5  F4 generated the required column with (AVAIL_UNTIL1 is null)? F1::A3 : F2::AVAIL_UNTIL1 as AVAIL_UNTIL..
```

Hope this hint will help you to the end result..